# .append() to JS created element with .on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user inputs a string, each character is split into an array and displayed as a "row" [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKak4.png). But when using the click event handler on a JS generated element, it isn't appending to the div that was clicked, but instead [are appended to #node_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3sTj.png). How do I append to the clicked div?

HTML

```
<input id='input' type='text'></input>
<button id='parse_seq' type="button">Parse</button>
<div id='node_list'></div>
```

JS

```
// Fetch input
var inseq = $("#input").val()

// Split each input character into array
var seqarr = inseq.split("")

// Loop over array to create div for each character
for (var i = 0, len = seqarr.length; i < len; i++) {

    // Prepend button to list
    if (i == 0) {
        CreateNewButton(i)
    }

    // Add node
    CreateNode(i+1,seqarr[i].toUpperCase())

    // Add button
    CreateNewButton(i+1)
}

// Create div
function CreateNode(id,content) {
    $("#node_list").append("<div id='seq_node" + id + "' class='seq_node'><span class='node_id'>" + id + "</span><span class='node_content'>" + content + "</span></div>")
}

// Create new button
function CreateNewButton(id) {
    $("#node_list").append("<div id='new_node" + id + "' class='new_node'>+</div>")
}

$('#node_list').on('click', '.new_node', function() {
    $(this).append(CreateNode(1,"new"))
    $(this).append(CreateNewButton(1))
})
```

Comment: Your CreateNode and CreateNewButton functions only attach content to #node_list.  Why are you creating all those IDs?

Comment: Your function `CreateNode()` isn't returning the newly created node; it's is *appending* it to `#nodelist` and not returning anything. Therefore your click handler at the very end won't do what you think it does. Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/400jctp1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your functions to receive an element as an argument. Then just append to that argument. For example:

```
// Create div
function CreateNode(id,content, node) {
    node.append("<div id='seq_node" + id + "' class='seq_node'><span class='node_id'>" + id + "</span><span class='node_content'>" + content + "</span></div>")
}

// Create new button
function CreateNewButton(id, node) {
    node.append("<div id='new_node" + id + "' class='new_node'>+</div>")
}
```

Then when you call the functions:

```
$('#node_list').on('click', '.new_node', function() {
    CreateNode(1,"new", $(this))
    CreateNewButton(1, $(this))
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Huge derp moment. I can't believe I overlooked this... :(